# Parsing data to Array count is 0

Tags: ios

I am trying to parse the response from data task to object of Array. The response contains data set but Array count is always 0.

```
Rest.shared.about(completionHandler: { json, error in

                    let about = json["about"] as? NSArray;
                    for abt in about! {
                        let obj = abt as? NSDictionary
                        let mId = (obj!["AboutId"] as? String)!
                        let mtitle = (obj!["AboutTitle"] as? String)!
                        let objabout = About(Id: mId, title: mtitle)

    //                    let objabout = About(Id: "1", title: "test")

                        self.aboutList.append(objabout)
                    }
                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()

})

print("data", self.aboutList.count)
```

Comment: Can You please add the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The API works asynchronously. the `print` line is at the wrong place.

Replace

```
    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
})

print("data", self.aboutList.count)
```

with

```
    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
    print("data", self.aboutList.count)

})
```